# How can I save SVG d attribute path elements using plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, matter.js

I'm working with [Matter.js](http://brm.io/matter-js/) SVG shapes and have the [demo](http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/#svg) working locally, and I'm trying to get it to work without the use of jQuery. Here is an [svg file](http://brm.io/matter-js/demo/svg/iconmonstr-user-icon.svg) for reference.

Demo code (the data is retrieved earlier using an `$.get('url-to-svg')` :

```
$(data).find('path').each(function(i, path) {
  console.log(Svg.pathToVertices(path));
  vertexSets.push(Svg.pathToVertices(path));
});
```

The jQuery path data neatly spaces out the d attribute:

`<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="st0" d="M 1 75.5 V 58.5 H 140 L 197 1.5 L 322 157.5 L 367 98.5 H 420 V 119.5 H 369 L 320 179.5 L 197 21.5 L 142 74.5 L 1 75.5 z"/>`

---

My code so far (I was able to perform the AJAX svg call to get the data):

```
let dataXml = parser.parseFromString(data, 'text/xml');
let path = dataXml.getElementsByClassName('st0')[0]; // i know about chaining .getAttribute('d') to get the d attribute
```

I've noticed that my path data looks like this (no spaces):

`<path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="st0" d="M1,75.5v-17h139l57-57l125,156l45-59h53v21h-51l-49,60l-123-158l-55,53L1,75.5z"/>`

---

The jQuery end result that I am looking for is the array of vertices:

```
[
  0: {x: 1, y: 75.5}
  1: {x: 1, y: 58.5}
  ...
]
```

I'm not sure what type of looping function jQuery is doing to loop through all the d attribute data in the path element.

Thanks :)

Comment: The problem doesn't appear related to jQuery, which is only handling requests and selecting the `<path>` elements and iterating them. Element selection can be done with `document.querySelector` or something else from that family. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65253422/how-to-use-a-font-awesome-svg-in-matter-js/65299500#65299500).